# MySQL Join Same Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the table 'meta_data' with the following fields:

- id
- post_id
- meta_key
- meta_value

I'd like to loop through and display a list of EACH post (`post_id`) that has an entry for `meta_key='abc'` but *not* one for `meta_key='def'`

Basically, every post that has a `meta_key='abc'` entry *should* have a `meta_key='def'` entry. I want to generate the list so I can add the missing `meta_key='def'` entries.

Comment: That's nice -- but what have you tried?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To achieve this you should use the [LEFT OUTER JOIN](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj18922.html) operation **joining the same table**.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM meta_data a
LEFT OUTER JOIN meta_data b ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND b.meta_value = 'def'
WHERE 
a.meta_value = 'abc'
AND b.post_id IS null
```

Answer (score 11):

Make an outer (left) join to itself, filtering on those records that *don't* match by looking for rows with a null id in the joined table:

```
select t1.* 
from meta_data t1
left join meta_data t2 on t2.post_id = t1.post_id and t2.meta_key='def' 
where t1.meta_key='abc'
and t2.id is null
```