# customize query result

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio

**I have 3 tables**

1. `tblIndividual`
2. `tblIndividualSpeciality`
3. `tblSpeciality`

One individual have multiple speciality, when I write query I get many rows depends  number of speciality to individual.
I need record in single row and each speciality have single column.

**This is the table structure**

[image]

**My query**

```sql
SELECT FirstName,LastName,SpecialtyName
FROM tblindividual ind,tblspecialty spec, tblindividualspecialty indspec    
where 
ind.pkIndividualID = indspec.fkIndividualID
and spec.SpecialtyCode = indspec.SpecialtyCode
and pkIndividualID = 355735;
```

**I received this format as result**

[image]

**But I need this format as result**

[image]

Can some one help me please.
I am using MySql database and development tool as Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What is the query you execute?

Comment: Select 
 FirstName,
    LastName,    
    SpecialtyName
    FROM tblindividual ind,tblspecialty spec, tblindividualspecialty indspec    
    where 
    ind.pkIndividualID = indspec.fkIndividualID
    and spec.SpecialtyCode = indspec.SpecialtyCode
    and pkIndividualID = 355735;

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576033/mysql-join-same-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem is that MySQL currently does not have the equivalent of SQL's PIVOT, and in overcoming that it also doesn't have a built-in concept of ROWNUM.

I created your tables with two separate individuals, four specialities of which the first Individual had 3 and the second had 2. I combined these into an interim table (temporary table if you prefer) using

```
INSERT INTO InterimResults
(
SELECT @row_number:=CASE WHEN @indId=pkIndividualId
                    THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END AS row_number,
       @indId:=pkIndividualId AS pkIndividualId, FirstName, LastName,
       SpecialityName
FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) n, 
     (SELECT @db_names:='') d, 
     (SELECT pkIndividualId,FirstName,LastName,SpecialityName
      FROM tblindividual ind
      inner join tblindividualspeciality indspec on ind.pkIndividualId=indspec.fkIndividualId
      inner join tblspeciality spec on spec.pkSpecialityCode=indspec.fkSpecialityCode) r
);
```

This gave me the following results (with my test data). Note if you run this in SQLFiddle's "Build Schema" pane all of the row numbers come out as 1, but the query works correctly in the "Run Sql" panel.

```
row_number pkIndividualId FirstName LastName   SpecialityName
1          1              Test      I-Health   Internal Medecine 
2          1              Test      I-Health   Family Practise 
3          1              Test      I-Health   Cardiology 
1          2              Test2     J-Health   Family Practise 
2          2              Test2     J-Health   Obstetrics
```

It is then quite simple to "pivot" this interim table using GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT  
  FirstName, LastName,  
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(row_number = 1, SpecialityName, NULL)) AS 'Speciality1', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(row_number = 2, SpecialityName, NULL)) AS 'Speciality2', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(if(row_number = 3, SpecialityName, NULL)) AS 'Speciality3' 
FROM InterimResults 
GROUP BY pkIndividualId;
```

References I used:
http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/qrytip.php?id=78
and http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/

Of course this assumes that you only want to report on the first 3 specialities, or each individual can only have up to 3 specialities - if there are others then you will need to use Prepared statements and dynamic sql - there is an example [at http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/](http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/)

Answer (score 0):

Use PIVOT query.

above link is for your reference.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1851916.aspx?Converting+Column+values+to+Rows+in+SQL+Query

This link is helpful for you.

I hope you solved your problem.

Comment: He is trying to make multiple rows, columns, which is the exact opposite of this. All he needs to do is join the table with itself.

Comment: This PIVOT is ok, but I have one Id have different values in a single column.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, SpecialtyName 
FROM tblindividual T1,tblspecialty T2, tblindividualspecialty T3 
WHERE T1.pkIndividualID = T3.fkIndividualID AND T2.SpecialtyCode =T3.SpecialtyCode AND pkIndividualID = 355735;
```

Comment: Would you consider adding some commentary before this SQL? Would you explain how it answers the question? Thanks.

Comment: This is just the OP's sql statement with the table aliases changed!