# Join wp_postmeta table to itself to find all entries that relate to a particular meta key & value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, join

I have a table **wp_postmeta** with these columns:

- meta_id
- post_id
- meta_key
- meta_value

and I would like to retrieve only the following entries:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------
| meta_id  | post_id  |    meta_key          |  meta_value      |
|----------|----------|----------------------|------------------|
|   1111   |   2222   | user_id              | 10               |
|----------|----------|----------------------|------------------|
|   1112   |   2222   | user_full_name       | Customer Name    |
|----------|----------|----------------------|------------------|
|   1113   |   2222   | renewal_order_total  | 00,00            |
|----------|----------|----------------------|------------------|
|   1114   |   2222   | order_bandeira       | Visa             |
|----------|----------|----------------------|------------------|
|   1115   |   2222   | order_token          | token            |
|----------|----------|----------------------|------------------|
|   1116   |   2222   | product_name         | Product X        |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my code, I have the `user_id`, I would like to get these values grouped 
by this user ID, as you saw above is a `meta_key` in this table I tried some queries but all of them were unsuccessful.

One of the queries I tried was based on answer of [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576033/mysql-join-same-table#_=_)

```
SELECT a.* FROM wp_postmeta a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND b.meta_value = 10 
WHERE a.meta_value = 10 AND b.meta_key = 'user_id'
```

The results that I get with this query is only the row with the `user_id`

```
----------------------------------------------------------------|
| meta_id  | post_id  |    meta_key          |  meta_value      |
|----------|----------|----------------------|------------------|
|   1111   |   2222   | user_id              | 10               |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: can you show one of them?

Comment: Please include the query you tried that was closest to working, so we can help you figure out how to make it work. We're not here to do the work for you, but we can help you get there yourself :) Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hey guys, I've updated my question.

Comment: And what was the result of this query - no results? the wrong results? Too many results? And what is "15" ... is it the user_id, because your example shows 10 - I presume that's just a typo?

Comment: @FluffyKitten Yes, it's the user_id. I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is right in the way it joins the table to itself, but the problem is that you are then telling it only to return rows where `a.meta_value = 10` instead of all the rows it found for that user_id.

Remove the `a.meta_value` condition from the WHERE like this, and it should work:

```
SELECT a.* FROM wp_postmeta a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta b ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND b.meta_value = 10 
WHERE b.meta_key = 'user_id'
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering, but I tried your query and didn't return any results

Comment: Can you compare it to your original query that returned one result? This is the exact same query except that it has even *fewer* conditions, so it should return more results, not less. It works perfectly for me (with a value that exists in my own db, of course). Are you running this directly in the database or through code?

Comment: Sorry, your answer worked. The problem was that the user_id's that I used to test with didn't exist. Thank's so much for your time!

Comment: @CesarHenriqueDamascena No problem, glad its working for you!